# elasticsearch multiple nic bind network interfaces

Tags: configuration, elasticsearch, network-programming, nic

#### introduction

when configuring elasticsearch I ran into a problem with binding the 
listening interfaces. 
somehow the documentation does not provide how to setup multiple network interfaces ([network def](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html) and [bind def](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-transport.html))

## problem description

my intention is to setup the `network.bind_host` as `_eth1:ipv4_` and  `_local_`

even when trying to setup the `bind_host` as `_local_` only,
 the elastic search port 9200 is still only reachable by eth1 (of course i have restarted the server)

solutions tried

i have tested the firewall configuration by setting up a netcat server and this one works perfectly for that port

#### so this results in 2 Questions:

1. how to configure multiple nics? (whats the notation?)
2. would i require to change the `network.publish_host` ?!

.

- any other pointers?

#### current configuration:

```
network.bind_host:    _eth1:ipv4_
network.publish_host: _eth1:ipv4_
network.host:         _eth1:ipv4_
```

#### also tested configuration:

```
network.bind_host:    _local_
network.publish_host: _eth1:ipv4_
network.host:         _local_
```

PS: 
afaik the publish_host is the nic for the inter-server communication

Comment: i know the traditional yaml list specification would be square brackets ... but it doesn't work (we are using version 1.* of elastic search )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Using a [YAML list](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759963) for the desired property:

   ```
   network.bind_host:
     - _local_
     - _en0:ipv4_
   ```
2. If I understand [this answer](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/What-s-the-difference-between-bind-host-and-publish-host-in-ElasticSearch-tp4057287p4057289.html) correctly, `publish_host` should be `_eth1:ipv4_`. Your `publish_host` has to be a one of the interfaces to which elasticsearch binds via the `bind_host` property.

---

The above linked answer is actually great, so I have to cite it here:

> **"bind_host"** is the host that an Elasticsearch node uses in the socket
>   bind call when starting the network. Due to socket programming model,
>   you can "bind" to an address. By referencing an "address", the socket
>   allows access to one or all underlying network devices. There are
>   several addresses with predefined semantics, e.g. 0.0.0.0 is reserved
>   for "bind to all network devices". So the "bind_host" address does not
>   necessarily reflect a single unique address.
>
> **"publish_host"** must be a single unique network address. It is used for
>   connect calls by other nodes, not for socket bind call by the node
>   itself. By using "publish_host" all nodes and clients can be sure they
>   can connect to this node. Declaring this single unique address to the
>   outside can be interpreted as "publishing", so it is called
>   "publish_host".
>
> You can not set "bind_host" and "publish_host" to arbitrary values,
>   the values must adhere to the underlying socket model.